# Kubernetes replica set make internal endpoints external?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm in the process of converting a docker-compose file to k8s. I used the k8s [kompose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose) program to automatically generate the service.

On the original docker setup port 80 and 443 are exposed.

I can see the ports referenced in my k8s object for the service:

```
"containers": [
  {
    "name": "router",
    "image": "myApp/router:latest",
    "ports": [
      {
        "containerPort": 80,
        "protocol": "TCP"
      },
      {
        "containerPort": 443,
        "protocol": "TCP"
      }
    ],
```

When I look from the UI I can see that the ports are correct for the pods but the service replica set shows this:

[image]

How do I open the ports externally for the replica set?

Comment: what do you mean by externally? external to the cluster, to the internet?

Comment: @jhernandez I want to open the ports up to the internet. Is that what "external endpoints" means in the screenshot?

Comment: for that you would have to use type:LoadBalancer for your service if you are using a cloud provider like aws/gcp you should get either a dns or an ip in the external endpoints section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kubernetes, you have several ways how to expose your service:

1. Expose ports of the Pod directly.
2. Use `Service` with `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` type. That is a recommended way and it works on L4.

   For `LoadBalancer`,  you need an external provider of load balancer itself, so it works only in a cloud and some other environments. If you have an on-premise installation on your own hardware, you should use `NodePort`type .
3. Use `Ingress`. That is also a recommended way, but it works on L7.

You can use the option you prefer, depending on your application.

Now your app is exposed only inside a cluster, because by default, Pods are available only for other Pods (it is like in docker-compose without `Expose` option).

Here are articles [about how to define a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service), what is [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and [how to use Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose-intro/) to expose your app.